# Formatting of table

Tags: tables

My code to generate a table is the following :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{ltxtable} 
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{7em}% Set numwidth of section

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \renewcommand\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{section}\arabic{figure}}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}
}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Granger causality from S\&P500 to Bitcoin price} 
    \label{tab:BTC_SP500}  
    $H_0$: 'BitCoin Price' do not Granger-cause S\&P500.
    \medskip\centering 
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
    Test statistic  & Critical Value    & $p$-value & df \\
    \midrule
     23.465636    & 37.652484     &  0.550 & 25 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \medskip\raggedright \\
    Conclusion: fail to reject $H_0$ at 5\% significance leve.
    \end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Granger causality from Bitcoin price on S\&P500 } % title of Table

    $H_0$: 'Close S\&P500' do not Granger-cause BitCoin Price.

    \medskip\centering 
    \begin{tabular}{rrrr}
    \toprule
    Test statistic &  Critical value & $p$-value & df \\
    \midrule
    28.421991 &       37.652484           & 0.289 & 25\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:SP500_BTC}
    \medskip\raggedright
    Conclusion: fail to reject $H_0$ at 5\% significance level.

    \end{table}


 \end{document}
```

But it produces the following [image]

And, I want the tables to be centered and to have the "Conclusion ..." below the table. Does anyone know how I could correct this? Thanks!

Comment: just put a blank line after the tabular so you get a new paragraph and delete the `\\ ` after `\raggedright` in the first table.

Comment: Please don't be in a hurry to "accept" the first (workable) answer. You are, of course, free to upvote any good answer immediately. Site guidelines strongly encourage waiting several hours, and maybe even a full day, before "accepting" an answer. That way, you won't discourage other readers of your query to post additional, and possibly superior, answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `\multicolumn{4}{l}{...}`, change tabular to `\begin{tabular}{cccc}` and remove `\raggedright`...

Note: A minimal working example contains minimal packages.

[image]

Minimal working example **(MWE)**:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Granger causality from S\&P500 to Bitcoin price} 
    \label{tab:BTC_SP500}  
    $H_0$: 'BitCoin Price' do not Granger-cause S\&P500.
    \medskip\centering 
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
    Test statistic  & Critical Value    & $p$-value & df \\
    \midrule
     23.465636    & 37.652484     &  0.550 & 25 \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{Conclusion: fail to reject $H_0$ at 5\% significance leve.}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Granger causality from Bitcoin price on S\&P500 } 
    \label{tab:SP500_BTC}
    \medskip\centering 
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{$H_0$: 'Close S\&P500' do not Granger-cause BitCoin Price.}\\
    \toprule
    Test statistic &  Critical value & $p$-value & df \\
    \midrule
    28.421991 &       37.652484           & 0.289 & 25\\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{Conclusion: fail to reject $H_0$ at 5\% significance level.}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Really urgent**: The captions and the explanations contradict each other. You must correct one or the other.

I suggest you use a single `table` environment, containing two `tabular` environments with associated `\caption`s, `\label`s, and associated descriptions. Use a single `\centering` instruction and no `\raggedright` instructions. Also, there's really no good to show six digits after the decimal marker. Two digits will do just as well -- better, in fact, because the likelihood is much higher that readers will bother to look at the test statistic.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,float}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5} % don't set low-level macro '\baselineskip' directly

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Granger causality from S\&P500 to Bitcoin price} 
    \label{tab:BTC_SP500}  

    \centering
    $H_0$: `BitCoin Price' does not Granger-cause S\&P500.

    \medskip 
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
    Test statistic  & Critical Value & $p$-value & df \\
    \midrule
     23.47      & 37.65      &  0.55 & 25 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \medskip
    Conclusion: Fail to reject $H_0$ at 5\% significance level.

    \bigskip
    \caption{Granger causality from Bitcoin price to S\&P500} 
    \label{tab:SP500_BTC}

    $H_0$: `Close S\&P500' does not Granger-cause BitCoin Price.

    \medskip
    \begin{tabular}{rrrr}
    \toprule
    Test statistic &  Critical value & $p$-value & df \\
    \midrule
    28.42 &       37.65      & 0.29 & 25\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \medskip
    Conclusion: Fail to reject $H_0$ at 5\% significance level.
    \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: This is much better (+1). @urpi I think you  can anccept this (and not my)   answer. I will delete my proposal, if its okay for you and you say: "Yes this answer works great for me".

Comment: @Bobyandbob - No need to delete your answer!!